# how to make queue animation function in ext4.0.2a?

Tags: javascript, extjs4

i'm trying to make my own loading screen.
it's like loading screen at ext 3.3.1 docs does, but using ext 4 as the core...

since the ext4 docs say `shift` animation is deprecated. so i replace shift with `puff` and slideout animation...

so far, i can make it..
here the code ;

```
var loading = Ext.get('loading');
var mask = Ext.get('loading-mask');

loading.puff({duration: 500}); //first fn

Ext.defer(function(){
    mask.slideOut('b',{duration : 500});//second fn

    Ext.defer(function(){
        mask.destroy();
        loading.destroy();//third fn
    }, 750);

}, 750);
```

but, code above is look awkward, cause i'm using defer to make it queued.
is there another way to make queued function ?
in ext3, they use callback function to make it works, but i can't find it at ext4 docs.
i even try it, still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify [`callback`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.fx.Anim-cfg-callback) config:

```
loading.puff({duration: 500}).animate({callback: function(){
    mask.slideOut('b',{duration : 500, callback: function(){
        mask.destroy();
        loading.destroy();//third fn
    }});//second fn
}}); //first fn
```

Notice the `loading.puff({duration: 500}).animate(` construction. It is a special workaround. It's needed because puff has limited set of params. And `callback` (due to some mistake, I quess. It has to be there) is not included in it.

[Here is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/6xvr9/).

**UPDATE**

Since `callback` is called not when the animation is completely ended it is better to use [afteranimate](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.fx.Anim-event-afteranimate) event in some cases (Especialy for the case of `loading.destroy();` being called in callback):

```
loading.puff({duration: 500}).animate({callback: function(){
    mask.slideOut('b',{duration : 500, listeners: {
        afteranimate: function(){
            mask.destroy();
            loading.destroy();//third fn
        }
    }});//second fn
}}); //first fn
```

Comment: thank's for reply,.. but it still show me an error,... have you try it at Chrome or FF (not at JSfiddle.net)?? mybe this why they not include callback on the docs??... but, i'll mark it as correct one, because your solution exactly works..

Comment: i also try your snippet at http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/6xvr9/embedded/ (result one). same error

Comment: @Warung, I've tried it only at Chrome at JSfiddle.net. I think the error is thrown because of `loading.destroy();` being called before animation is actualy ended. Here is [another demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/6xvr9/2/) which uses `afteranimate` event instead of `callback`.